# Find the Mobius Transformation that satisfies the following

Tags: complex-analysis

So this question comes from Complex Analysis by Ahlfors, Section 3.3 Problem 4. It asks to find a Mobius transformation that takes $|z|=2$ into $|z+1|=1$, $-2$ to $0$, and $0$ to $i$. I know this problem has been answered before but I was wondering what I am doing wrong or what is the missing step. Any Mobius transformation will have the following form
$$Tz = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$ Given the information about the points $-2$ and $0$, we get that $$Tz = \frac{az+2a}{cz-2ai}.$$ Now using Theorem 15 (pg: 82) in the book we know that if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are circles such that $TC_1=C_2$, then for any $z \in \bar{\mathbb{C}}$ (extended complex plane) we have $(Tz)^*=Tz^*$. The definition of $z^*$ is given in this section as well. Anyways, I used this when $z=0$ and got that $c=-a(i+1)$. So we have $$Tz = \frac{az+2a}{-a(1+i)z-2ai}.$$ However here is where I get stuck. I am not sure how to determine this constant $a$.

Any advice?

Comment: The constant $a$ completely cancels out, and you're done! Notice that we always have the freedom to multiply $a,b,c,d$ by an arbitrary nonzero constant (that doesn't change the function $Tz$), so there are really only three degrees of freedom, not four.

Comment: Just divide numerator and denominator by $a$ and the problem goes away.

Comment: @saulspatz: I feel like I should have seen that ... thank you lol